# Send image to database using Kendo Ui Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik

In my MVC project , i have a form that gives the user the possibility to upload an image with Kendo Ui Upload.
This is my view:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model DevelopmentNotesProject.Models.NoteForm


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("form").kendoValidator();
    });

    function limitUpload()
    {
        if ($("span.k-filename").html() != "" || $("span.k-filename").html() != "undefined") {
            $("div.k-dropzone div.k-button.k-upload-button input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }

    function enableUploadafterRemove()
    {
        $("div.k-dropzone div.k-button.k-upload-button input").removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    function onSuccess(e) {
        limitUpload();
    }

    function onRemove(e) {
        alert("innn");
        enableUploadafterRemove();
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {


    });
</script>

<style>
    form,h2 {margin:0 auto;max-width:900px}
</style>

<section id="NoteForm">
    <h2>New note to save</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Note to save</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
                    @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
                        .Name("Title")
                        .Value("")

                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)


                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Text)
                    @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.Text)
                        .Name("Text")


                    )

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Text)

                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.languageId)
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.languageId)
                          .Name("languageId")
                          .DataTextField("Text")
                          .DataValueField("Value")
                          .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.languageslist)
                          .OptionLabel("Select a language")
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.languageId)
    @*Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Language)*@
                    <!--Without Kendo-->
                    @*Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.languageId, new SelectList(DevelopmentNotesProject.DAL.LanguageAccess.getLanguages().OrderBy(c => c.Value), "Value", "Text"), "Select country", new { @Class = "myDropDownList" })
                        @*Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Language)*@
                </li>

                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.img)
                    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                        .Name("files")

                        .Async(a => a
                            .Save("Save", "MyNotes")
                            .Remove("Remove", "MyNotes")


                        )
                            .Events(events => events
                                 .Upload("onSuccess")
                                 .Remove("onRemove"))                              
                    )
                </li>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </fieldset>
    }
</section>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Right now, the image is saved in the add_data folder of my project. 
With this block of code:

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

             file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        }
    }

    // Return an empty string to signify success

    return Content("");
}
```

The problem is i send all the form data to database when the user submits the whole form:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Add(NoteForm model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)))
            {
                try
                {
                    DAL.NoteAccess.insertNote(model.Title, model.Text, model.languageId);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyNotes");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    //ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I can't find a solution to get the image in my Noteform object (in the function above).
By the way, is it better to save the image in the app_data folder first before sending it to database or there is a better approach ?
Thanks for your help

EDIT:
The model:

```
[Table("note")]
public class NoteForm
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Language")]  
    public int languageId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("languageId")]
    [UIHint("LangDropDown")]
    public virtual Language language { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Photo")]  
    public byte[] img { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]

    public int userId { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your problem? You have `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` as parameter of your action. 
Just get files from this Enumerable and set them to your NoteForm in proper attributes.

**Update**
You should switch of async post of files in upload control:

```
.Async(a => a.Save("Save", "MyNotes")
             .Remove("Remove", "MyNotes")
```

Just remove this code before and your files parameter of action will not be null.

Comment: files is null unfortunately

Comment: Can you stop on breakpoint of this action and look at Request.Form property? Is there any key where you have this files? If no, you should show me your view model and your view.

Comment: I have updated my question with full view dans model.Thanks for your help